# How to shred a Huge XML Files With 600M between threads

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

Can you please tell me how to shred huge XML Files With 800M between threads!

Which mechanism should I use?

Just for information I am loading the file using `untangle`:

```
doc = untangle.parse(xml)
```

Comment: I want to load the file one time

Comment: What is it that you think threads will give you?